# CPU Cache implementation in C or C++ or SystemC

Tags: c++, c, hardware, modeling, cpu-architecture

I need a very basic C or C++ source code of CPU cache. Google didnt help me find a proper one.
The implementation only needs to provide the most fundamental functionality of a cache.
For ex, in C++:

```
class Cache{
  ... //parameter setup of way, capacity, etc
  public: access(addr){
             miss=inspect(addr);
             if(miss){ fetch_mem(addr); replace_policy...;}
             else{...}              
           }
 ...
};
```

Does someone know some source code as such?

Thanks!!

Comment: Hehe, no. I would be too lazy if it is, right?

Comment: Start with a LRU cache and go from there...

Comment: You want to model the cache component within the CPU itself? That very much depends on your entire model. I'd use a sub-functon, and call it at doAction() to load instructions into an array of some sort until I decide to pass the instructions to some instruction set simulator.

Comment: What exactly are you modeling?  Is this an L1 cache, or an L2 cache?  Is it direct-mapped, or is it multi-way associative?  Do you care about virtual address translation?  Are there I/O devices?

Comment: For the inner workings of cache: http://lwn.net/Articles/252125/ I don't know of any C or C++ model though.

Comment: You've already made a start, why not just take it further?

Answer (score 1):

my 2 cents: use the strategy pattern so to be able to model different "most fundamental functionality of a cache" ideas. obviously, you already have some kind of implementation. one thing you might consider is looking at your code include cache sizes parameters, to try simulate L1 versus L2 (although it is much more complicate in real life)